# Загрузка данных о пользователе в Async Task через API Appwrite

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Хочу как-то переформатировать код в Async Task чтобы сначала данные загружались с облака Appwrite, а уже после этого они высвечивались в виджетах. Дело в том, что код снизу выполняет задачу, но если пользователь будет постоянно тыкать на профиль, то приложение вылетит. Да и вообще, такие вещи нужно оформлять через Async Task.

Я пытался сделать это с помощью AsyncTask самостоятельно, разделив части на `doInBackground()`
и `onPostExecute()`. Но почему-то данные не загружались в виджеты. В идеале чтобы ответ был с объяснением.

Вот код который без AsyncTask

```
String masterKeyAlias = null;
        try {
            masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
        try {
            sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                    "secret_shared_prefs",
                    masterKeyAlias,
                    getContext(),
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            );

            String loggedStatus = sharedPreferences.getString("savedStatus", "");
            String loggedEmail = sharedPreferences.getString("savedEmail", "");
            String loggedPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("savedPassword", "");
            String loggedSessionId = sharedPreferences.getString("savedSessionId", "");
            String loggedUsername = sharedPreferences.getString("savedUsername", "");
            String loggedCreateData = sharedPreferences.getString("savedCreateData", "");
            String loggedMainInfo = sharedPreferences.getString("savedMainInfo", "");
            String loggedSessionCreateData = sharedPreferences.getString("savedSessionCreateData", "");
            String loggedAvatarBase64String = sharedPreferences.getString("savedAvatar", "");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            Client client = new Client(getContext())
                    .setEndpoint("api_endpoint_link") // Your API Endpoint
                    .setProject("project_id"); // Your project ID

            Account account = new Account(client);


            if (!(loggedStatus.startsWith("true"))) {
                RelativeLayout profileInfoLayout = getView().findViewById(R.id.profileInfoLayout);
                profileInfoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            if (loggedStatus.startsWith("true")) {
                account.getSession(
                        loggedSessionId,
                        new Continuation<Object>() {
                            @NotNull
                            @Override
                            public CoroutineContext getContext() {
                                return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void resumeWith(@NotNull Object o) {
                                try {
                                    if (o instanceof Result.Failure) {
                                        Result.Failure failure = (Result.Failure) o;
                                        throw failure.exception;
                                    } else {
                                        io.appwrite.models.Session currentSession = (Session) o;


                                        String sessionStatus = "true";
                                        currentSessionString = currentSession.getId();

                                    }
                                } catch (AppwriteException appwriteException) {
                                    editor.clear();
                                    editor.putString("savedStatus", "false");
                                    editor.apply();

                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ProfileFragment.this.getContext().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrongSessionId), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                            toast.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (Throwable th) {
                                    Log.e("ERROR", th.toString());

                                }
                            }
                        });


                account.get(new Continuation<Object>() {
                    @NotNull
                    @Override
                    public CoroutineContext getContext() {
                        return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void resumeWith(@NotNull Object o) {
                        try {
                            if (o instanceof Result.Failure) {
                                Result.Failure failure = (Result.Failure) o;
                                try {
                                    throw failure.exception;
                                } catch (Throwable e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                }
                            } else {
                                io.appwrite.models.Account currentAccount = (io.appwrite.models.Account) o;
                                String currentUsername = (String) ((io.appwrite.models.Account) o).getName();
                                String currentCreateData = (String) currentAccount.getCreatedAt();
                                Preferences currentAccountPrefs = (Preferences) currentAccount.getPrefs();
                                String currentMainInfoString = (String) currentAccountPrefs.getData().getOrDefault("main_info", "nope");
                                String currentAvatarBase64String = (String) currentAccountPrefs.getData().getOrDefault("avatar_img", "nope");;

                                String accountPasswordUpdate = currentAccount.getPasswordUpdate();

                                String accountEmail = (String) currentAccount.getEmail();


                                String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);

                                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                                        "secret_shared_prefs",
                                        masterKeyAlias,
                                        ProfileFragment.this.getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                                        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                                        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
                                );


                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.US);


                                try {
                                    Date dateLastPasswordUpdate = sdf.parse(accountPasswordUpdate);
                                    Date dateSessionCreate = sdf.parse(loggedSessionCreateData);
                                    if (dateLastPasswordUpdate.after(dateSessionCreate)) {
                                        account.deleteSession(
                                                currentSessionString,
                                                new Continuation<Object>() {
                                                    @NotNull
                                                    @Override
                                                    public CoroutineContext getContext() {
                                                        return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void resumeWith(@NotNull Object o) {
                                                        try {
                                                            if (o instanceof Result.Failure) {
                                                                Result.Failure failure = (Result.Failure) o;
                                                                throw failure.exception;
                                                            } else {

                                                            }
                                                        } catch (Throwable th) {
                                                            Log.e("ERROR", th.toString());
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        editor.clear();
                                        editor.putString("savedStatus", "false");
                                        editor.apply();

                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ProfileFragment.this.getContext().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrongCredentials), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                                toast.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    System.out.println(accountPasswordUpdate);
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                                if (!(loggedEmail.equals(accountEmail))) {
                                    account.deleteSession(
                                            currentSessionString,
                                            new Continuation<Object>() {
                                                @NotNull
                                                @Override
                                                public CoroutineContext getContext() {
                                                    return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void resumeWith(@NotNull Object o) {
                                                    try {
                                                        if (o instanceof Result.Failure) {
                                                            Result.Failure failure = (Result.Failure) o;
                                                            throw failure.exception;
                                                        } else {
                                                            editor.clear();

                                                            editor.putString("savedStatus", "false");
                                                        }
                                                    } catch (Throwable th) {
                                                        Log.e("ERROR", th.toString());
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                    editor.clear();
                                    editor.putString("savedStatus", "false");
                                    editor.apply();

                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ProfileFragment.this.getContext().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrongCredentials), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                            toast.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }



                                editor.putString("savedUsername", currentUsername);
                                editor.putString("savedCreateData", currentCreateData);
                                editor.putString("savedMainInfo", currentMainInfoString);
                                if (currentAvatarBase64String != null) {
                                    editor.putString("savedAvatar", currentAvatarBase64String);
                                }
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        } catch (java.lang.RuntimeException unkException) {
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ProfileFragment.this.getContext().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrongInternetConnection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Throwable th) {
                            Log.e("ERROR", th.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });





                TextView loginWarningTextView = getView().findViewById(R.id.loginWarningTextView);
                loginWarningTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Button loginWarningButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.loginWarningButton);
                loginWarningButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                LinearLayout loginWarningButtonLayout = getView().findViewById(R.id.loginWarningButtonLayout);
                loginWarningButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                TextView profileInfoNameTextView = getView().findViewById(R.id.profileInfoNameTextView);
                profileInfoNameTextView.setText(loggedUsername);
                TextView profileInfoMainTextView = getView().findViewById(R.id.profileInfoMainTextView);
                profileInfoMainTextView.setText(loggedMainInfo);
                ImageView profileInfoAvatarImageView = getView().findViewById(R.id.profileInfoAvatarImageView);
                if (loggedAvatarBase64String != null) {
                    decodedString = Base64.decode(loggedAvatarBase64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    profileInfoAvatarImageView.setImageBitmap(decodedBitmap);
                }
            }
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (AppwriteException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Comment: Почему AsyncTask? Я как будто вернулся на 10 лет назад)
Почему не RX?
А в идеале переписать на Kotlin + корутины

Comment: @Circassian я не изучал Kotlin а изучал Javу, что за RX (фреймворк?). И в чем суть?

Comment: В AsyncTask нет ничего сложного, пробуйте сами, обновляйтесь в onPostExecute(), добавьте код в вопрос, а этот бесполезен.

Comment: У вас данные и сейчас не отображаются в виджетах. только со второго раза запуска этого кода. Код надо не в asynctask переносить, а разделить на разные функции. И вызывать те, которые нужны, а не всю портянку с многочисленными if'ами....  
Если в качестве хранилища вы используете SahredPreferences, то, например, подпишитесь на их изменения, и выводите данные там... Разделите получение, сохранение и показ данных. Гораздо легче станет ориентироваться.

Comment: Короче, я переписал все в AsyncTask и все работает но появилась ошибка. Когда пользователь туда сюда открывает и закрывает Fragment с виджетом профиля то выходит ошибка. Куда я могу добавить новый код и лог ошибки?

Comment: В итоге я и те баги пофиксил, но инфо виджет о пользователе появляется позже. На это можно как то повлиять или это зависит от качества интернета?

Comment: @FreddyBear у тебя есть доступ к интернету, а ты спрашиваешь что такое RX) Чувак, асинктаски задепрекейтили несколько лет назад. А морально они устарели лет 8 назад. Потом всё коммьюнити юзало RX, который тоже успел устареть к текущему моменту) Учи котлин + корутины + компоуз